# Проверка двумерного массива на наличие отрицательных чисел

Tags: javascript, jquery, массивы

Я не пойму, почему она все время **true** возвращает, ведь все же стандартно?

```
$(function () {
    var mm = [
        [-1, 0],
        [0, -1],
        [0, 2]
    ];

    var checkArr = function (sArr) {
            var result;
            i = 0;
            $.each(mm, function () {
                // если в массиве есть число ниже нуля, то результат функции ЛОЖЬ
                if (sArr[i][0] < 0 || sArr[i][1] < 0) {
                    result = false;
                }
                // иначе же ИСТИНА
                else result = true;
                ++i;
            });
            return result;
        }

    console.log(checkArr(mm));

});
```

Answer (score 3):

У вас проверяются все элементы массива, поэтому значения переменной result будет иметь такие значения по ходу выполнения:

1. result = false;
2. result = false;
3. result = true; // при последней итерации

Именно последнее значение и будет возвращено. Вам надо просто остановить дальнейшую итерацию, если отрицательное значение в массиве найдено

Answer (score 0):

все правильно у выполняется **++i** выходит получаемый второй элемент это **sArr[1][0]** тоесть 0 а ноль не меньше самого себя и выходит true

ставьте операторные скобки

```
 else 
    {    
      result = true;
       ++i;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Результат всегда один и тот же, потому что значение result вычисляется для **каждого** элемента массива, а поскольку для последнего элемента это true, то и функция возвращает true.